# Attribute access on invalidly named columns

Tags: pandas

Using Pandas 0.11.0, I am trying to read in data from a CSV file with the following structure:

```
Date/Time   Data1    Data2
  5/10/13      23     17.0
  5/10/14      20     17.1
  5/10/15      27     17.3
```

In order to create a new column based on existing data, I would use [attribute access](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#attribute-access) of the fashion:

```
df["Result"] = 2.0 * df.Data2
```

However, because "Date/Time" is not a valid attribute name, what is the recommended way to create a new column based on the data in the "Data/Time" column?  I would prefer not to have to manually specify all column names when using the read_csv method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `df['Date/Time']`. The attribute access style of selecting a column, `df.column_name`, is merely a convenient shortcut for `df['column_name']`. It is simply not possible to use this convenience when your column names are not [valid Python identifiers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), as in 'Date/Time'. You can change the name, or you can use the long form.

Comment: Ah, that worked.  I had been trying to guess if there was some canonical transform like "DateTime" or "Date_Time" happening.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Since you are new, I will point out that it is courteous to "accept" answers if they resolve your question.

Comment: @DanAllan I think the word ["identifier"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Comment: OK, I almost went with that. Will revise. (Thanks!)